# SQL Server script fails b/o Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

When I execute a T-SQL script on a remote tool (enterprise production environment), it fails with error:

> Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text

NB: the **SQL Server 2012** database I issue the scripts against has `Properties > Options > Collation` set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.5058.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools  11.0.5058.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 5.0 6.0
Microsoft Internet Explorer    9.11.9600.18314
Microsoft .NET Framework    4.0.30319.34209
Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64) 
 Oct 19 2012 13:38:57 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)